# Find $P(Y\ge 1+\frac{4}{3}X)$ when pdf is given

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let X,Y be two continuous random variable and their joint pdf is given by:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{2}{625}(20-x-2y); 0 \le x \le 5;0 \le y \le 5$$ 
$$f(x,y)=0; \quad otherwise$$

Find $P(Y\ge 1+\frac{4}{3}X)$.

I cannot figure out how to tackle this problem. I know that I have to do double integration but not sure how to get the bounds as I thought $1+\frac{4}{3}X$ needs to be incorporated into the bounds as well. Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: $Y$ can't be any larger than 5 so solving for $X$ in $5=1+4X/3$ will give you the upper bound for $X$.  Then $Y$ will have the bounds $1+4X/3$ to 5.

Comment: Have you tried writing the probability using definition?                                   $$\iint_{\{(x,y):y\geqslant1+4x/3\}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

$$=\int_0^5 \left(\int_{1+4x/3}^5 f_{Y\mid X=x}(y\mid x)\,dy\right)\,f_X(x)\,dx$$

Comment: x will vary from 0 to 3 only not 0 to 5 .

Comment: @cyberboy that makes sense. I drew the graph of the support and I got the same bounds.

Comment: @JimB thanks for pointing that out. I drew the support function and was able to calculate the probability

Comment: @StubbornAtom, took your advice and set up the integration in a similar fashion. My bounds were a bit different though. I used x varies from 0 to 3/4y-3/4 and y varies from 5 to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 < y < 5
0 < x < 5

now you need to find  P(Y > 1 + 4x/3)
draw the region [0,5] * [0*5]  and the line y = 1 + 4x/3
you have to take the upper region bounded by line y =  5  and y = 1 +4x/3 and x= 0

hence limits are
y varies from 1 + 4x/3  to 5
and x varies from 0 to 3

https://www.symbolab.com/solver/multiple-integrals-calculator/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B3%7D%5Cint_%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B4x%7D%7B3%7D%7D%5E%7B5%7D%20%20%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B625%7D%5Cleft(20-x-2y%20%5Cright)dy%20dx

Integrating we get required probability as 28/125 = 0.224

Comment: I integrated with the bounds :y varies from 1 to 5 and x varies from 0 to 3/4y-3/4. You integrated dydx and I did dxdy but got the same answer, i.e. 0.224. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: yes, your limits are also correct .